# Unable to create Virtualenv using virtualenv-2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I have 2 versions of Python in Centos Linx- Python2.6 & Python2.7..Im trying to create a virtualenv using my virtualenv-2.7 and get the following error.

```
[root@linuxhost PythonProjects]# virtualenv-2.7 --distribute ENV
New python executable in ENV/bin/python2.7
Not overwriting existing python script ENV/bin/python (you must use ENV/bin/python2.7)
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /home/prem/PythonProjects/ENV/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 2696, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 429, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 443, in add_entry
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1722, in find_in_zip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1298, in has_metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1614, in _has
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1488, in _zipinfo_name
AssertionError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO is not a subpath of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv-2.7')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 820, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 956, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 898, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/prem/PythonProjects/ENV/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Comment: A suggestion: Use virtualenvwrapper [link](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem once.

I think maybe it is the pip problem.

So I follow the below link's instructions and install pip for python 2.7.

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ez_setup.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 pip
```

Then

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 env
```

worked.

please take a look into the link below.
https://github.com/0xdata/h2o/wiki/Installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-Follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only#installing-and-configuring-distribute-setuptools

fyi